# What is causing a NullPointerException in dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged for Flutter 2.10 app?

Tags: android, flutter

Since updating my app to the latest stable version of Flutter (2.10) targeting API 31, I am seeing in Crashlytics lots of exceptions similar to this:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int)' on a null object reference
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1619)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1619)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1619)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1619)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2646)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8665)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

The crash occurs mostly in the background. I saw some other posts about the Google ad control, but I am not serving ads. I do display a Google map control using hybrid composition, but I have no idea if that is even related. I need some ideas on what is causing this and how to track it down.

Comment: Hi. Exactly the same thing is happening to me, also unrelated to ads. Did you by any chance migrate your app pre 1.12 (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects), or is it a new app?

Comment: The app is about a year old and I have been migrating consistently as new stable versions of Flutter are released. As to this exception, it is happening very frequently yet nobody is complaining. I'm wondering if it is happening as the app is being shut down and users are not seeing it.

Comment: I think that is the case. I can see logs from my own device in Crashlytics, but I haven't really experienced any visible issues.

Comment: Are you using Google maps or anything else that might be using hybrid composition?

Comment: Same here! Upgraded my app to last Flutter + iOS + Android versions and lot of users have crashs...

Comment: Are you deeplinking to a WebView by any chance? 
I can consistently reproduce when I open a WebView, close the WebView, and background the app.

Answer (score 1):

This crash is a known issue with Flutter v2.10.

Please upgrade to v2.10.1 with `flutter upgrade --force` which resovles the issue.

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97679